# extracting specified line numbers from file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file with a list of address it looks like this (ADDRESS_FILE)

```
0xf012134  
0xf932193  
.  
.  
0fx12923a
```

I have another file with a list of numbers it looks like this  (NUMBERS_FILE)

```
20  
40  
.  
.  
12
```

I want to cut the first 20 lines from ADDRESS_FILE and put that into a new file
then cut the next 40 lines from ADDRESS_FILE  so on ...

I know that a series of sed commands like the one given below does the job

```
sed -n 1,20p ADDRESSS_FILE > temp_file_1
sed -n 20,60p ADDRESSS_FILE > temp_file_2
.  
.
sed -n somenumber,endofilep.  ADDRESS_FILE > temp_file_n
```

But I want to does this automatically using shell scripting which will change the numbers of lines to cut on each sed execution.

How to do this ???

Also on a general note, which are the text processing commands in linux which are very useful in such cases?

Comment: Wrt text processing commands, a lot of it can be done directly by your shell so get to know it intimately. If you're on a GNU based system I would recommend reading `coreutils.info` and `sed.info`. For more complicated tasks `awk` and `perl` are good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your line numbers are in a file called `lines`, sorted etc., try:

```
#!/bin/sh

j=0
count=1
while read -r i; do
  sed -n $j,$i > filename.$count  # etc... details of sed/redirection elided
  j=$i
  count=$(($count+1))
done < lines
```

Note. The above doesn't assume a consistent number of lines to split on for each iteration.

Since you've additionally asked for a general utility, try [split](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split). However this splits on a consistent number of lines, and is perhaps of limited use here.

Comment: You shouldn't use a for loop to read lines in a file. It happens to work in this case, only because there is one word per line. It is overall bad practice. Use `while read -r line; do ...; done < file`.

Comment: It works in this case because he's *specified* it as such. See the question.

Comment: This is not justification to do it the wrong way. [Don't Read Lines With For](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: I don't disagree that there are better ways and it's worth pointing it out. To downvote the complete solution (including detailing alternative options) seems particularly petty, however

Comment: Well this worked but I dont understand how it worked :) Dont just give fish to a hungry man , teach him to fish :) ...... What about the tools one needs to learn for text manipulation ?   Please answer so that I too can give the same help to someone as I have got from you people.

Comment: @Deepthought - re tools, see my reference to split. As to how the above works, it's instructive to substitute echo in place of sed. The read is essentially assigning each line in turn to the variable i

Answer (score 1):

```
size=$(wc -l ADDRESSS_FILE)
i=1
n=1
while [ $n -lt $size ]
do
  sed -n $n,$((n+19))p ADDRESSS_FILE > temp_file_$i
  i=$((i+1))
  n=$((n+20))
done
```

or just

```
split -l20 ADDRESSS_FILE temp_file_
```

(thanks Brian Agnew for the idea).

Comment: I think $ cant be used in sed.I got errors. Instead use this       `a=2
b=4
sed '/$a/,/$b/p' input_file > new_file`

Comment: @Deepthought: sorry, it must be $(()) not $() in many cases in my example; I fixed that. `$n` and `$((n+20))` can be used in sed of course because that is no in sed actually, that is in shell; and the expands it

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative that reads directly from the `NUMBERS_FILE`:

```
n=0; i=1
while read; do 
  sed -n ${i},+$(( REPLY - 1 ))p ADDRESS_FILE > temp_file_$(( n++ ))
  (( i += REPLY ))
done < NUMBERS_FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

An ugly solution which works with a single `sed` invocation, can probably be made less horrible.

This generates a tiny sed script to split the file

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
count=0
sed -n -f <(while read -r n ; do
    echo $((sum+1),$((sum += n)) "w temp_file_$((count++))" ;
done < NUMBERS_FILE) ADDRESS_FILE
```

Comment: Well this worked but I dont understand how it worked :) Dont just give fish to a hungry man , teach him to fish :) ...... What about the tools one needs to learn for text manipulation ?   Please answer so that I too can give the same help to someone as I have got from you people

Comment: Sorry, here's what this does: It goes over the `NUMBERS_FILE`, generating a sed write command for each set of lines, eg, `1,20 w temp_file_0`, `21,60 w temp_file_1` and so on. `sed` processes each address range in turn, writing the output into the relevant file